# NOT your standard Curl error: WAMP/local copy of remote Magento site, curl_setopt() not defined

Tags: magento, configuration, localhost, wamp

I have created a local copy of my remote store (Magento Community 1.6.2.0) using WampServer 2.2E:

1. Cleared entire Magento cache on remote site
2. exported remote MySql database using phpMyAdmin
3. tar'd up the entire remote public_html folder and downloaded to local PC
4. Recreated directory structure locally under C:\wamp\www\
5. created a new database locally (I'm using WAMPserver) with appropriate user/pass/DBname according to /app/etc/local.xml -- note: dbase host in local.xml is "localhost"
6. imported database with no errors
7. modified mage_core_config_data table's baseurl variables to both point to http://www.localhost.com/
8. modified local .htaccess to prevent configuration that would result in crashing as well as to modify the rewrite rule that does the 301 redirect for domain.com to www.domain.com (I changed domain.com to be localhost.com).
9. deleted everything in var/cache, var/session, var/tmp, and the system /tmp folder, as suggested in another Q&A
10. verified that WAMP has curl PHP extension enabled

So now everything loads except for the admin panel.  When I go to http://localhost.com/index.php/admin and log in, the error is:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt() in C:\wamp\www\includes\src\Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl.php on line 52
```

I assume that curl_setopt() is defined in the curl library, and that extension is enabled in WAMPserver.. anyone know what's going on with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that my php version is 5.4.3.  Wampserver.com offers a 2.2E package with 5.3.13, but that also doesn't work.

I got this to work only by finally trying wampserver 2.2D, which has php version 5.3.10.  I used the 64-bit installer -- didn't try the 32-bit but I assume it will work..  This information is notably absent from the magentocommerce.com wiki entry on setting up Magento with WampServer.

New problem is now no page other than the home page loads (404 not found happens for all product pages and categories).  This is solved by ensuring that Apache rewrites are enabled (wampserver menu->apache->apache modules->rewrite_module)

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt()

This error mean that php5-curl is not available/activated on your system. You should be able to activate it through the wamp configuration panel.

For linux users, install php5-curl through your packet manager.